# C++ Returning pointer from function

Tags: c++, pointers

This seem to have been asked/answered many times, but I still feel I'm not sure.

Is there difference between these two methods, and is either of them Ok to use.

```
SomeClass* GetSomeClass(){
    SomeClass *sc = new SomeClass();
    // do something with sc
    return sc;
}
```

Vs

```
SomeClass* GetSomeClass(){
    SomeClass *sc = new SomeClass();
    // do something with sc
    SomeClass *rSc;
    rSc = sc;
    return rSc;
}
```

Comment: You want a quick recap on pointers?

Comment: shit, meant to say return sc, rsc etc

Comment: Why don't you just compile both and inspect the output (preferably as assembly) for differences?

Comment: There is no logical difference. Depending on optimization capabilities of the compiler, it might actually produce the same code (likely to, in fact) for both cases. Without optimization, second version will yield slightly (as in nanoseconds) less performant code due to extra allocating and copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are exactly the same.

The first code in words:

```
SomeClass pointer sc = new SomeClass();
return SomeClass pointer sc
```

The second code in words

```
SomeClass pointer sc = new SomeClass();
SomeClass pointer rSc = SomeClass pointer sc
return SomeClass pointer rSc
```

As you can read/ see for yourself there is no difference since the second statement in the second example is redundant anyways

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between the two. They both construct an object and return a pointer to it, leaving the caller to `delete` the object when they're done with it.